# Servo delay on direction change

Tags: arduino, servo

I'm using a SG-90 servo and sweeping left and right between two values. 
My problem is that there is a distinct delay of about 500ms between direction changes. I would like the position of the servo to be predictable, but due to this at direction changes it is not.

```
bool servoDir = true;
int servoCnt = 90;
int servoInc = 1;
int servoMin = servoCnt - 5;
int servoMax = servoCnt + 5;

void loop() {
    if (servoDir) {
      dx = servoInc;
      if (servoCnt > servoMax) {
        servoDir = false;
      }
    } else {
      dx = -servoInc;
      if (servoCnt < servoMin) {
        servoDir = true;
      }
    }
    servoCnt += dx;
    servo.write(servoCnt);
    // delay or other code here (mine is 40ms)
}
```

I've tried both the Arduino Servo library and the VarspeedServo library. They both show the same thing.

What is the cause of this and what can I do about it?

**Update**

So if I up the speed at direction change, like so:

```
int extra = 5;
void loop() {
    if (servoDir) {
      dx = servoInc;
      if (servoCnt > servoMax) {
        dx -= extra;
        servoDir = false;
      }
    } else {
      dx = -servoInc;
      if (servoCnt < servoMin) {
        dx += extra;
        servoDir = true;
      }
    }
    servoCnt += dx;
    servo.write(servoCnt);
    // delay or other code here (mine is 40ms)
}
```

the delay disappears, but the servo position does become a lot less predictable.

Comment: You would experience exactly these symptoms if servoMin and servoMax were out of the servo range....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would experience exactly these symptoms if servoMin and servoMax were out of the servo range....  Which they are.

More seriously, these servos are not very precise. Incrementing by 1 at a time is probably the issue.  You are experiencing some form of backlash.

You should check and **clamp** the count against the range AFTER incrementing/decrementing.  That's one of the basic rules of embedded programming.  Lives may be at stake, or equipment destroyed when sending out out of range values.

```
bool servoDir = true;
int servoCnt = 90;
int servoInc = 1;             // <-- exclusively use this to control speed.
int servoMin = servoCnt - 5;  // <-- this range is a bit short for testing
int servoMax = servoCnt + 5;

void loop() {

    // 'jog' the servo.
    servoCnt += (servoDir) ? servoInc : -servoInc;

    // past this point, all position jogging is final
    if (servoCnt > servoMax) 
    {
        servoCnt = servoMax;
        servoDir = false;
    }
    else if (servoCnt < servoMin) 
    {
        servoCnt = servoMin;
        servoDir = true;
    }

    servo.write(servoCnt);

    // 40ms sounds a bit short for tests.
    // 100 ms should give you a 2 seconds (0.5Hz) oscillation
    delay(100);
}
```

Comment: Range is 0-180 and I only use 85-95. I tried 100 ms too, same problem.

Comment: Accepted it as answer as incrementing with too small steps doesn't agitate the motor enough. It'll only start moving after several increments. There isn't nothing to do about it unfortunately.